# search box with fragment does not respond

Tags: android, fragment

Hello I have a problem when I search the page tomorrow the process is successful but when I search the page today there is a problem , I used Fragment

the problem here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiHGME6i97I&feature=youtu.be

codes :

```
public void btn_search(View view) {
    TextView txtexample = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtexample);
    txtexample.setText("hello");
}
```

fragment days

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.weather.Fragment_days">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtexample"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment days

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_days, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

and fragment today and tomorrow are empty.

please help me , two weeks ago I was looking for a problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (note two lines with `txtexample`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_days, container, false);

    TextView txtexample = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtexample);                                       
    return v;
}
```

and

```
 public void btn_search(View view) {
     txtexample.setText("hello");
 }
```

Comment: when searching the page today or 10 days, exit the program

Comment: it will obviously gets crash because you are on the first fragment and you are changing the view of last fragment on search button click which is resting in onresume() method

Comment: can you set an example?